# Proper Replacement of Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have one Activity Called A. The activity has 1 Frame Layout in which Fragments are used. I have two Fragments, Fragment1 and Fragment2. When the Activity is launched, Fragment 1 fills the Frame Layout.

Fragment1 also contains a button that when clicked replaces it with Fragment2 within that same Frame Layout. My question is this, when I click that Button in Fragment1 should I implement that code so that

A) Activity A gets notified of the onClick in the Fragment through an interface using some type of Boolean value and then proceeds to replace it with Fragment2.

OR

B)Implement the code that replaces Fragment1 with Fragment2 within Fragment1 itself For example:

```
private FragmentTransaction ft;
private Button registerButton, resetButton;
private Fragment fragment;

public LoginFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    registerButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.register_button);
    resetButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.reset_button);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.register_button: {
            fragment = new RegisterFragment();
            ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone explain why one over the other? Thanks so much!

Comment: `I have one Activity Called A. The activity has 1 Frame Layout in which Fragments are used. I have two Fragments, Fragment1 and Fragment2. When the Activity is launched, Fragment 1 fills the Frame Layout.

Fragment1 also contains a button that when clicked replaces it with Fragment2 within that same Frame Layout. My question is this, when I click that Button in Fragment1 should I implement that code so that`       Can you please add this code to your question

Comment: I would go with option A because the Fragment itself should not know its state, i.e. have control of the FragmentManager of the Activity

Comment: Ok thanks, I added the example of the code for option B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, what I do is use an interface of some sort that lives in the fragment being replaced (in this case Fragment 1). Your parent activity then would implement this interface, and thus building a contract between the activities that are the parent of that particular fragment.

When you press your button (or whatever event happens to signal replace), you grab your activity casting it to that interface, and call the particular method.

e.g. Signaling event within the fragment

```
( (MyFragmentListener) getActivity()).onActionHappens();
```

Where MyFragmentListener is the inner class of your Fragment and onActionHappens() is the method that sends the signal. This effectively creates a contract between your fragment and any Activity that hosts the fragment. When your action happens, you let the activity know and the activity then overrides the appropriate method to handle the event.

There are other ways to do this, but at the simplest level this is how it can be done.

**Why not option B**

Option B creates a tight coupling between fragments, which you don't necessarily want. In practice you want the coupling to be between the fragment, and it's host (or parent) which is the Activity. Also, there could be many activities that use that fragment so you abstract away details about the particular activity that uses it by just calling getActivity(). In this case, coupling the fragment and the Activity is acceptable, since of course the two are coupled anyways. We know this because a fragment cannot live without an associated Activity, so it is okay to take advantage of the that tight coupling.

**Summary**

Pick option A. It is the cleanest route, and avoids assuming implementation details that you have to do in option B.

It is also the basic solution you have without any external libraries or details required. If you want a more advanced solution, checkout Otto (made by Square) [Link to the library here](https://github.com/square/otto)

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response, that makes sense

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!